# Can I verify if a dynamic text is in a stored variable with Selenium IDE?

Tags: variables, selenium-ide, assert

I am testing a system and I encountered following issue: I must assert that  certain elements are on the page only if an admin is logged in. To do so  I must first verify the logged in user is on the list of admins. This is what I have done so far:

```
<tr> //storing the username in a variable
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>css=#myAccount > span</td>
    <td>user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>echo</td>
     <td>${user}</td>
     <td></td>
</tr>
<tr> //this is where all the admins ID´s are stored
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>css=#new_user</td>
    <td>allAdmins</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${allAdmins}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['allAdmins'].search(storedVars['allAdmins']);}</td>
    <td>validate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${validate}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The result that I get is always 0 as in false. I tried to write instead of `.search(storedVars['allAdmins']);}`       `search("srv_admin");}` since is one of the admins users in the list but I still get a false. Is is even possible to do that with selenium IDE?

Comment: Can you provide any sample code to show how the list of admin users and the name of the current user shows? may be something to do with how the list is formatting causing the user name to not be found

Comment: @Manoj Kumar I actually found the error. I was using the wrong javascript command .search. I tried it with .contains and the expression was evaluated to true. I tried to post the solution here but I could not find my question. I only saw it now because your comment popped up. Thanks a lot for wanting to help